# Jmeter Data Parametrization for both body and inside field values

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have a Jmeter project whose task is to load test a GraphQL API with multiple types of requests. In that i need to parametrize both the request body and one parameter inside each request as well.

For Example, consider the below CSV as input test data.

[CSV Test Data  -  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4alV.png)

I would like to read the 4 rows from the excel and for each row, create a graphql request(from column B). Next, for each request, i would like to generate 5 variations based on any of the input parameters(City and Designation for example as shown). Then, i would want Jmeter to run these 20 requests under one thread group till the thread group's expiry time.

How do I parametrize the above scenario in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot read data from Excel files, you will have to implement "variation" requests using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries

References:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, how about the CSV Config data set?